# Android Orfox - Clearing RAM messes tabs up

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, android, mobile

I have found that clearing RAM using the stock Samsung memory manager transfers all standard tabs in Orfox to private mode - and makes them reload.

When clearing RAM, reloading does happen in Firefox.  Transferring ordinary tabs to private mode does not happen with Firefox.

Suggestions?  Am I in the right place for this?

Please treat this tor noob gently - I do try to find my own answers before I post.

Comment: I believe Orfox is in private mode by default, like Tor Browser? I'd be concerned about what that tool was doing to Orfox's state (in that it may be breaking some of it) but I don't know how it does what it claims to do.

Comment: @canonizing: Private mode is similar to incognito in Chrome. It turns off cookies and/or JavaScript. I also don't know about the RAM clearing, but when my phone (Moto G3) has too much going on and runs out of RAM, Orfox doesn't remember my tabs at all. I'm forced to use a different browser because my 1 GB runs out frequently.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Samsung devices, but the behaviour you described is very odd and warning by itself: it seems that application is being run in some kind of debugging or tracing container. Because - regardless of the OS, memory manager and so forth - *any kind* of forced garbage collecting should **not** affect running applications memory: it's not freed and not queued for garbage collecting. You can be experiencing a privacy intrusion, I'm afraid...